# Is there a way to adjust the python version for a blender addon by changing the code of it?

Tags: python

I'm not really into coding, but the error message looks quite simple, can I just rewrite it in some file or something similar? I'm using 4.1 Release Candidate Version.

[image]

Comment: Often times python stop running the add-on on the first "exception" (as it's called).   This doesn't mean it's the only problem and you'd be "jumping into the deep end of  the swimming pool" if you crack open the egg!   You'd be better off contacting the developers of the add-on (usually a button in Preferences for the add-on "Report a bug").   You may have to get to this button but running the previous blender version that works with the add-on.

Comment: There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation. Since that's a built-in Blender addon you should report it as a bug as soon as possible. As @james_t says as it's obviously not been updated to support the python version that Blender 4.1 will be using.

Comment: NodePreview is not a builtin addon. The [page on blendermarket](https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview) specifically states that only versions up to 4.0 are supported, it's not surprising since 4.1 is not officially released. You should try and reach the addon maintainer on the network you used to purchase the addon. Cheers

Comment: Also note python versions and blender versions are not the same thing, although it's kind of confusing since they look alike with the 3.xx